# How to install dh_virutalenv 0.8 or 0.9?

Tags: 14.04, virtualenv

I have DHVE installed:

```
ii  dh-virtualenv                                         0.6-1                                               all          wrap and build python packages using virtualenv
```

but i need to isntall version 0.8 or 0.9 but how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via a PPA with unstable versions

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:dh-virtualenv/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After that, you should have version 0.10.

---

Only for information, the latest version in the officially Ubuntu repositories is currently 0.7.2 for Wily.